# Minecraft, summon without ~

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to use the following command to summon an skeleton horse to the players location:

> execute {name} ~ ~ ~ /summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~

However due to donationcraft removing the '~', I need a version to do this without the use of '~'.

Does anybody have an idea on how to complete this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you trying to make buying a horse possible through donationcraft and need to set the command for it? I suggest contacting Enjin and ask them to allow ~ characters, as they are immensely useful.

Comment: A mod removes tilda notation from commands? Your best option is probably to get rid of that mod.  There's no good reason for a mod to do that, which would make me weary of what else it's doing.

Comment: I indeed am trying to do the selling like you said MrLemon, Ive contacted Enjin in the meantime, now lets hope they can (will..) enable it.
As for the mod, I dont think that is the problem, given that running the command on console isn't a problem at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't.** The only thing you can do without the relative coordinate operator is summon a horse at a specific coordinate. You cannot do any operations that require relative coordinates if the operator is disabled.